# How to search query radius with limit and pagination in GeoHash, DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, geospatial

I'm using query radius method for search by radius.

Here is python implementation.

```
geoDataManager.queryRadius(
        dynamodbgeo.QueryRadiusRequest(
            dynamodbgeo.GeoPoint(lat, lon), radius, sort = True
        )
    )
```

Now i want add pagination and get total count. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations with the dynamodb-geo library. Although low level DynamoDB Query requests return paginated results, this library automatically pages through the entire result set.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/dynamodbgeo/

Answer (score -3):

Only way i see is going into source code and changing things based on your need